# spring cloud rabbit configuration tries to connect to localhost 5672

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

There are tons of examples where java code is being used to configure pure rabbit, but spring boot related documentation is another story.

My requirement is pretty basic - Single queue, Single exchange, One dead-letter queue with predefined names. Some HA policy. Deployed to pivotal cloud-foundry.

The app should use cloud connection factory, so I don't have to specify connection info.
The app should create queue/exchange if they don't exist.
I need a controller that can use rabbitTemplate to send msgs.
I need a listener to process those messages, in multiple consumer threads.

I have tried to do properties-only approach. And I have tried tons of beans  to do this. For some reason it doesn't want to connect to cloud service!

I am using spring boot app and running it in pivotal cloud foundry

Code

```java
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
@Profile("cloud")
@Slf4j
public class RabbitMQConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {

    final static String MAIN_QUEUE_NAME = "pricing";
    private final static String QUEUE_EXCHANGE_NAME = "pricing-exchange";
    private final static String DEAD_LETTER_QUEUE_NAME = "pricing-dl";

    @Autowired
    RabbitProperties rabbitProperties;

    @Bean("pricingQueue")
    @Primary
    public Queue pricingQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(MAIN_QUEUE_NAME)
                .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", "")
                .withArgument("x-dead-letter-routing-key", DEAD_LETTER_QUEUE_NAME)
                .withArgument("x-queue-master-locator", "min-masters")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue deadLetterQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(DEAD_LETTER_QUEUE_NAME)
                .withArgument("x-queue-master-locator", "min-masters")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(QUEUE_EXCHANGE_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding pricingBinding(@Qualifier("pricingQueue") Queue pricingQueue,
                                  DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(pricingQueue).to(exchange).with(MAIN_QUEUE_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
}
```

I think this is happening because spring boot created the listener container and not me

Error

> [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'management.health.status-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorProperties'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createArgumentArray:777]- Autowiring by type from bean name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration' via constructor to bean named 'management.health.status-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthIndicatorProperties'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'healthIndicatorRegistry'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createArgumentArray:777]- Autowiring by type from bean name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' via factory method to bean named 'org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6483f5ae'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'rabbitHealthIndicator'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'rabbitTemplate'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.rabbitmq-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitProperties'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createArgumentArray:777]- Autowiring by type from bean name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration' via constructor to bean named 'spring.rabbitmq-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitProperties'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'rabbitConnectionFactory'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createArgumentArray:777]- Autowiring by type from bean name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' via factory method to bean named 'spring.rabbitmq-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitProperties'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createArgumentArray:777]- Autowiring by type from bean name 'rabbitTemplate' via factory method to bean named 'rabbitConnectionFactory'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jsonMessageConverter'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'rabbitMQConfig'

...

> [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createArgumentArray:777]- Autowiring by type from bean name 'viewResolver' via factory method to bean named 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1dde4cb2'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'amqpAdmin'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createArgumentArray:777]- Autowiring by type from bean name 'amqpAdmin' via factory method to bean named 'rabbitConnectionFactory'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration$MessagingTemplateConfiguration'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'rabbitMessagingTemplate'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createArgumentArray:777]- Autowiring by type from bean name 'rabbitMessagingTemplate' via factory method to bean named 'rabbitTemplate'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createArgumentArray:777]- Autowiring by type from bean name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration' via constructor to bean named 'spring.rabbitmq-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitProperties'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'rabbitListenerContainerFactory'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createArgumentArray:777]- Autowiring by type from bean name 'rabbitListenerContainerFactory' via factory method to bean named 'simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.createArgumentArray:777]- Autowiring by type from bean name 'rabbitListenerContainerFactory' via factory method to bean named 'rabbitConnectionFactory'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'directRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer'

...

> [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getSingleton:213]- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'management.server-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementServerProperties'
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.:264]- Inferred argument type for public void com.gm.gsmc.pricing.messenger.service.PricingMessageListener.handleMessage(com.gm.gsmc.pricing.domain.queue.QueueMessage) is class com.gm.gsmc.pricing.domain.queue.QueueMessage
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.setConcurrentConsumers:166]- Changing consumers from 1 to 5
>   [main] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.start:1293]- Starting Rabbit listener container.
>   [main] [INFO ] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareConnection:482]- Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
>   [main] [INFO ] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.checkMismatchedQueues:1713]- Broker not available; cannot force queue declarations during start: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>   [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-1] [INFO ] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareConnection:482]- Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
>   [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-1] [ERROR] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary:1764]- Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s). java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)\n    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]\n  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]\n   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_212]\n    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]\n at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]\n at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]\n   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar!/:5.4.3]\n  at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1102) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar!/:5.4.3]\n  at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1054) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar!/:5.4.3]\n  at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:484) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]\n   ... 11 common frames omitted\nWrapped by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)\n   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]\n   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:530) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]\n   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:702) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]\n at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:214) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]\n at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2076) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]\n at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2050) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]\n   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2030) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]\n   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:403) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]\n   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1777) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]\n   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1758) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]\n  at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1195) [spring-rabbit-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]\n  at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1041) [spring-rabbit-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]\n at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]\n

Comment: You need to show your `application.yml` (or `properties`) and any other configuration. Clearly, you somehow have two connection factories because the declarations were successful to the cloud broker `Declarations finished`.

Comment: I tried yml way and gave up, I have no spring rabbitmq properties at all

Comment: It feels like RabbitProperties object has default of localhost:5672 and it is being used by connection factory before yml/cloud config can wire in correct stuff

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have those `amqpAdmin` calls in your bean definitions (although they are commented out). You must NEVER talk to the broker in a bean definition - it's too early in the lifecycle.

The error in the first log leads me to believe that was not commented out. That log looks truncated too - there should be `Caused by` parts. You should never truncate a log when asking a question. A partial stack trace is useless.

> Factory method 'msgQueueBinding' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

This clearly shows an attempt to connect from the `msgQueueBinding` method.

The following logs show the queue/exchange/binding being successfully declared when the listener starts.

I am guessing your admin calls are happening before the cloud code has replaced the connection factory bean definition.

Comment: I cleaned up that and I was still getting errors now if I create SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory myself, things work, I think its RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration that is initializing things too early

Comment: I don't see how; the auto configuration won't try to connect; the connection is not established until the container starts (after all bean creation is complete). When connection is created the admin is called to do the declarations. Overriding boot's container factory won't make a difference; so something else is going on. DEBUG logging of the bean creation sequence should tell all.

Comment: since I use config server, container starts and then refresh is called, so some things are happening twice, I ll clean up my code and put in new logs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointers Gary

This is basically the config that "works"

If I take RabbitTemplate or Container Factory off, I start seeing errors

I took some code from RabbitAutoConfiguration and did my best to read the same yml and use the properties in the beans I create

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableRabbit
    @Profile("cloud")
    @Slf4j
    public class RabbitMQConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {

    final static String MAIN_QUEUE_NAME = "pricing";
    private final static String QUEUE_EXCHANGE_NAME = "pricing-exchange";
    private final static String DEAD_LETTER_QUEUE_NAME = "pricing-dl";

    @Autowired
    RabbitProperties rabbitProperties;

    private void debug(String step) {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (CachingConnectionFactory) connectionFactory().rabbitConnectionFactory();
        log.info("===> debug connection with {} {} ", step, connectionFactory.getClass().getName());
        log.info("host {}", connectionFactory.getHost());
        log.info("port {}", connectionFactory.getPort());
        log.info("vh {}", connectionFactory.getVirtualHost());
        log.info("user {}", connectionFactory.getUsername());
        log.info("Auto recovery {}", connectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().isAutomaticRecoveryEnabled());
        log.info("RabbitProperties {}", ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(rabbitProperties));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("DuplicatedCode")
    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(MessageConverter messageConverter) {
        debug("rabbitTemplate");
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory().rabbitConnectionFactory());
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        if (rabbitProperties != null) {
            RabbitProperties.Template properties = this.rabbitProperties.getTemplate();
            PropertyMapper map = PropertyMapper.get();
            if (properties.getRetry().isEnabled()) {
                rabbitTemplate.setRetryTemplate(createRetryTemplate(properties.getRetry()));
            }
            map.from(properties::getReceiveTimeout).whenNonNull().as(Duration::toMillis)
                    .to(rabbitTemplate::setReceiveTimeout);
            map.from(properties::getReplyTimeout).whenNonNull().as(Duration::toMillis).to(rabbitTemplate::setReplyTimeout);
            map.from(properties::getExchange).to(rabbitTemplate::setExchange);
            map.from(properties::getRoutingKey).to(rabbitTemplate::setRoutingKey);
            map.from(properties::getDefaultReceiveQueue).whenNonNull().to(rabbitTemplate::setDefaultReceiveQueue);

        }
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    private RetryTemplate createRetryTemplate(RabbitProperties.Retry properties) {
        PropertyMapper map = PropertyMapper.get();
        RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
        SimpleRetryPolicy policy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        map.from(properties::getMaxAttempts).to(policy::setMaxAttempts);
        template.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
        map.from(properties::getInitialInterval).whenNonNull().as(Duration::toMillis)
                .to(backOffPolicy::setInitialInterval);
        map.from(properties::getMultiplier).to(backOffPolicy::setMultiplier);
        map.from(properties::getMaxInterval).whenNonNull().as(Duration::toMillis).to(backOffPolicy::setMaxInterval);
        template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
        return template;
    }


    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        debug("rabbit listener");
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory().rabbitConnectionFactory());
        factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(rabbitProperties.getListener().getSimple().getConcurrency());
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(rabbitProperties.getListener().getSimple().getMaxConcurrency());
        factory.setPrefetchCount(rabbitProperties.getListener().getSimple().getPrefetch());
        factory.setMissingQueuesFatal(false);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = connectionFactory().rabbitConnectionFactory();
        debug("amqpAdmin");

        RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
        rabbitAdmin.initialize();
        //This is what puts HA policy on the queue it seems
        Properties queueProperties = rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(MAIN_QUEUE_NAME);
        log.debug("queueProperties {}", queueProperties);
        return rabbitAdmin;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        debug("postConstruct");
    }

    @Bean("pricingQueue")
    @Primary
    public Queue pricingQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(MAIN_QUEUE_NAME)
                .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", "")
                .withArgument("x-dead-letter-routing-key", DEAD_LETTER_QUEUE_NAME)
                .withArgument("x-queue-master-locator", "min-masters")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue deadLetterQueue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable(DEAD_LETTER_QUEUE_NAME)
                .withArgument("x-queue-master-locator", "min-masters")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(QUEUE_EXCHANGE_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding pricingBinding(@Qualifier("pricingQueue") Queue pricingQueue,
                                  DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(pricingQueue).to(exchange).with(MAIN_QUEUE_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory() {
        DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
        factory.setMessageConverter(consumerJackson2MessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2MessageConverter consumerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are using pivotal cloud foundry, then add dependency "io.pivotal.cfenv:java-cfenv-boot:2.3.0", this will resolved localhost issue, it has cf postprocessors which will replace the rabbitMQ properties